# Set FFmpeg volume mixer with delay functionality

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, volume-mixer

I want to use different volumes for each input file and append each file with other on some delay
I am using this command to add delay.
How I will add volume for each file in same command.

```
ffmpeg -i s1.mp3 -i s2.mp3 -filter:a -i s3.mp3  -filter_complex "[1]adelay = 5s | 5s[a1];[2]adelay = 10s | 10s[a2];[0:a][a1][a2]amix = inputs =3[a]" -map "[a]" output7.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [volume filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume):

```
ffmpeg -i s1.mp3 -i s2.mp3 -i s3.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]volume=2,adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[2]volume=0.5,adelay=10s:all=1[a2];[0:a]volume=3[a0];[a0][a1][a2]amix=inputs=3[a]" -map "[a]" output7.mp3
```

Comment: Thankyou so much..It Worked. :D

Comment: Can you please tell how to set the output volume in same command, I am applying filter a graph that gives error   "Filtergraph 'volume=1.5' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream."

Comment: @livinghacks `-filter_complex "[1]volume=2,adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[2]volume=0.5,adelay=10s:all=1[a2];[0:a]volume=3[a0];[a0][a1][a2]amix=inputs=3,volume=2[a]"`